# PDFTable Unicode support

Tags: fpdf

I'm using PDFTable from http://www.vanxuan.net/tool/pdftable/ which is based on FPDF class. I managed to export HTML table to pdf using PDFTable. However, I'm facing one issue. The non-English characters are all displayed in gibberish. It doesn't seem that it supports unicode. The language I'm trying to display is Arabic and Russian.

I could, theoretically, create a similar class to PDFTable, which is inherited from FPDF, and develop it from scratch to add unicode support. But it's a lot of work. Has anyone done something like that and perhaps could share? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For unicode support, the best way is to use tFPDF from http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php. It's a fork of FPDF with specifically to support unicode. The class is based on the latest FPDF version 1.7.